# Update database connection password using EF Core interceptors

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to use EF Core [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) for catching database connection issues, like invalid username/password, update them by using an API call and re-try the same query?

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19211240/1260204, you could manually check if the credentials are valid which would be better than trying to do this after with a interceptor at which point it might be too late to successfully recover.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea behind this is that we should use an external API call for updating the password when this is being changed. So, I am looking for a solution to catch the invalid password exception, retrieve the new password, update the connection string and continue with the query.

Comment: Look at [Connection Resiliency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps perform a check once in your app before running current code, here is a language extension.

```
public static class Extensions
{

    public static async Task<(bool success, Exception exception)> CanConnectAsync(this DbContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await Task.Run(async () => await context.Database.CanConnectAsync());
            return (result, null);
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {
            return (false, localException);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public static async Task Demo()
{
    await using var cn = new CustomerContext();
    var (success, exception) = await cn.CanConnectAsync();
    if (success)
    {
        // connected 
    }
    else
    {
        // examine exception variable
    }
}
```

Comment: But this means I have to check the connection every time I am trying to use the DbContext, so I should use this extension everywhere, while using an interceptor is just one place.